# onUpgrade not called in sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm making a update of my app. In this update, I have to add a field in a table in my Sqlite DB.

Here is the file to manage a single instance of my DB:

DatabaseManager.java

```
public class DatabaseManager {
private AtomicInteger mOpenCounter = new AtomicInteger();

private static DatabaseManager instance;
private static SQLiteOpenHelper mDatabaseHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

public static synchronized void initializeInstance(SQLiteOpenHelper helper) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DatabaseManager();
        mDatabaseHelper = helper;
    }
}

public static synchronized DatabaseManager getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                DatabaseManager.class.getSimpleName()
                        + " is not initialized, call initializeInstance(..) method first.");
    }

    return instance;
}

public synchronized SQLiteDatabase openDatabase() {
    if (mOpenCounter.incrementAndGet() == 1) {
        // Opening new database
        mDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    return mDatabase;
}

public synchronized void closeDatabase() {
    if (mOpenCounter.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
        // Closing database
        mDatabase.close();

    }
}
```

Then, the main Db File is :

```
public class PdvHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String TAG = "com.spmkt.mobile";

// All Static variables
// Database Version
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

// Database Name
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb.db";
....

public void dropAndCreateMetrics() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseManager.getInstance().openDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + MetricsHandler.TABLE_METRICS);
    db.execSQL(MetricsHandler.CREATE_TABLE_METRICS);
    DatabaseManager.getInstance().closeDatabase();
}

}
```

then, I want to add a column in the alerta table :

AlertaHandler.java

```
public class AlertaHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public AlertaHandler(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
        int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
    DatabaseManager.initializeInstance(this);

}

public AlertaHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, PdvHandler.DATABASE_NAME, null,
            PdvHandler.DATABASE_VERSION);
    DatabaseManager.initializeInstance(this);

}

SQLiteDatabase db;

public static final String TABLE_ALERTAS = "alertas";

private static final String ALERTA_ID = "id";
private static final String ALERTA_CAPTURA_ID = "captura_id";
private static final String ALERTA_MENSAJE = "mensaje";
private static final String ALERTA_URGENT = "urgent";  // This is the column to add
private static final String ALERTA_SYNC = "sincronizado";

// private static final String ADD_URGENT_COLUMN =
// "ALTER TABLE "+TABLE_ALERTAS+" ADD COLUMN "+ +" ";

public static String CREATE_ALERTA = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ALERTAS + "("
        + ALERTA_ID + " INTEGER  " + "PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + ALERTA_CAPTURA_ID + " INTEGER," + ALERTA_URGENT
        + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, " + ALERTA_MENSAJE + " TEXT" + ", "
        + ALERTA_SYNC + " INTEGER )";

public static String DROP_ALERTA = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + TABLE_ALERTAS+"'";

public ArrayList<Mensaje> getUnSincronizedMessage() {

    ArrayList<Mensaje> lMensajes = new ArrayList<Mensaje>();
    // Select All Query
    Mensaje message;
    String messageQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ALERTAS + " WHERE "
            + ALERTA_SYNC + "= 0";

    SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseManager.getInstance().openDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(messageQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            message = new Mensaje();
            message.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ALERTA_ID)));
            message.setCapturaId(cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(ALERTA_CAPTURA_ID)));
            message.setMessage(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(ALERTA_MENSAJE)));
            int urgent = cursor
                    .getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ALERTA_URGENT));
            message.setUrgent(urgent == 0 ? false : true);
            message.setSincronizado(cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(ALERTA_SYNC)));

            lMensajes.add(message);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    DatabaseManager.getInstance().closeDatabase();
    return lMensajes;
}

public void addMessage(Mensaje m) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseManager.getInstance().openDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ALERTA_CAPTURA_ID, m.getCapturaId());
    values.put(ALERTA_MENSAJE, m.getMessage());
    values.put(ALERTA_URGENT, m.isUrgent() ? 1 : 0);
    values.put(ALERTA_SYNC, m.getSincronizado());

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_ALERTAS, null, values);
    DatabaseManager.getInstance().closeDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

public boolean existsMensaje(Mensaje m) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseManager.getInstance().openDatabase();
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + TABLE_ALERTAS + " WHERE "
            + ALERTA_ID + "=" + m.getId();
    Cursor mCount = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    mCount.moveToFirst();
    int count = mCount.getInt(0);
    mCount.close();
    DatabaseManager.getInstance().closeDatabase();
    if (count == 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public void updateMessage(Mensaje m) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseManager.getInstance().openDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ALERTA_ID, m.getId());
    values.put(ALERTA_MENSAJE, m.getMessage());
    values.put(ALERTA_SYNC, m.getSincronizado());
    values.put(ALERTA_URGENT, m.isUrgent());
    values.put(ALERTA_CAPTURA_ID, m.getCapturaId());

    // updating row
    db.update(TABLE_ALERTAS, values, ALERTA_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(m.getId()) });
    DatabaseManager.getInstance().closeDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    int upgradeTo = oldVersion + 1;
    while (upgradeTo <= newVersion) {
        switch (upgradeTo) {
        case 2:
            try{
                db.execSQL(DROP_ALERTA);
                db.execSQL(CREATE_ALERTA);                  
                Log.e(TAG,DROP_ALERTA);
                Log.e(TAG,CREATE_ALERTA);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Crashlytics.logException(e);
            }
            break;
        }
        upgradeTo++;
    }
}
```

I read that onUpgrade will only run when getWritableDatabase runs, but I don't understand well what's going on...

Should I alter my tables in PdvHandler, because it is the file which define DB version?
Should I alter my tables in each handler file? ( I have 1 handler x table = 10 handlers)

I'm a little bit lost !
Any suggestion would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

> Should I alter my tables in PdvHandler, because it is the file which define DB version? Should I alter my tables in each handler file? ( I have 1 handler x table = 10 handlers)

You should have only one `SQLiteOpenHelper` per database file.

`onUpgrade()` gets called when the version of the database schema you request with the parameter supplied to `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor is larger than the schema version stored in the database file. If the database file was already upgraded to your requested version by one sqlite helper working on the same database file, `onUpgrade()` is not invoked on another helper.

Also, you should not catch exceptions in `onCreate()` or `onUpgrade()`. If there's a problem, the exception should be thrown outside the method.

See also: [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run)

Comment: ok. I have 10 handlers that extends SQliteOpenHelper. So the solution should be that all my handlers extends one only super class that extends SQliteOpenHelper???

Comment: No. You'd still have 10 different helpers. Just have one class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`. You can split the table-specific operations to separate classes but there can be only one helper class per database file.

Comment: So where should I store my instance to my SQLiteOpenHelper class??? I tried in myApplication Class ( The one that extends Application), but I get weird errors after that.